# How to show association fields only after click on link_to_add_association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

Hi guys i am using the very useful gem: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

My goal here is to display my association fields only when i click on link_to_add_association.

I should not display the fields when i load my form page.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Cheers

documents partial

```
<h4><%= t('.title') %></h4>

<ul class="documents-list">
  <%= f.fields_for :property_documents do |property_document_fields| %>
    <% unless property_document_fields.object.new_record? %>
      <%= render '/shared/properties/property_documents_list', f: property_document_fields %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group property-documents">
  <%= f.fields_for :property_documents do |property_document_fields| %>
    <% if property_document_fields.object.new_record? %>
      <%= render '/shared/properties/property_document_fields', f: property_document_fields %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<span class="pull-left">
  <%= link_to_add_association t('.add_document'),
                              f,
                              :property_documents,
                              partial: 'shared/properties/property_document_fields',
                              class: 'btn btn-primary',
                              data: {
                                association_insertion_node: '.property-documents',
                                association_insertion_method: :append
                              } %>
</span>
```

documents fields

```
<li>
  <%= link_to admin_property_path(@property.id, property: { property_documents_attributes: { id: f.object.id, "_destroy" => true }}), remote: false, confirm: "Really delete #{f.object.name} ?", method: :put do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash" style="padding-right: 10px; color: #d9534f;"></i>
  <% end %>
  <% if f.object.document.present? %>
    <%= link_to f.object.name, f.object.document.url, target: :_blank %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to f.object.name, url_with_protocol(f.object.url), target: :_blank %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cocoon doesn't generate nested association by default. Maybe you do it your documents model or controller, such as

```
document.property_documents.build
```

Comment: already do it, and if you see, i only show the association fields if it is a new record.

Comment: You show this block always with `unless property_document_fields.object.new_record?` expression, or what. You need to remove `build` method if you did it

Comment: i do show the form for adding a new association only when it is a new record, like this: <ul class="list-group property-documents">
  <%= f.fields_for :property_documents do |property_document_fields| %>
    <% if property_document_fields.object.new_record? %>
      <%= render '/shared/properties/documents/property_document_fields', f: property_document_fields %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

well after trying a lot of stuff, i found this solution...

removed `property_photos.build` from edit method in the controller

and in the form, just let it be like:

```
<ul class="list-group property-photos">
  <%= f.fields_for :property_photos do |property_photo_fields| %>
    <% if property_photo_fields.object.new_record? %>
      <%= render '/shared/properties/photos/property_photo_fields', f: property_photo_fields %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

cheers